# Adding .lib files in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2010, and they changed a lot since Visual Studio 2008. These options were changed: the header includes, the lib directory to add, and all changed.

I followed a series of tutorials to do that, but in the other version I just had to add the mylib.lib string in the textfield, but now I look over and over, and I can't find a place to paste that mylib.lib to link with my project.

Where can I find it?

Comment: To do what?  Import a lib file in to your project?

Comment: Yes I want to link the libcurl.lib to my project. Its already in the lib folder but I need to link it, to do that I need to find the place to type the libcurl.lib so the project knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for how to get a lib file imported in to your project, you can do this either by editing the project settings, under Linker>Input:

[image]

...or you can use a `#pragma`...

```
#pragma comment( lib, "MyLib.lib" )
```

I typically add this right in to the header file for the library I want to import.  Alternatively, you can add it to any header or CPP file in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to do it this way, right in code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "mylib.lib")
```

This way you don't need to look for the field you need under project settings.

See also: [What does "#pragma comment" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484434/what-does-pragma-comment-mean)

Comment: Roman Thanks for answering, where do I put this code? And what exactly is this "lib" variable, and where should my "mylib.lib" be placed? in /lib normally ? thanks!

Comment: Right in code, like this: http://www.assembla.com/code/roatl-utilities/subversion/nodes/trunk/DxError/DxError.cpp#ln11 (line 11)