# Why and when do we need to use #pragma

Tags: c++, windows, pragma

I was learning a winsock client server program and came up through `#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")`. Understood its need here. But what are the other instances I can use it and why do I need to use it?

Comment: It is already extensively documented in the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx), no need to repeat it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#pragma` 's are implementation defined compiler commands.

That means, each compiler could treat or support pragmas in a different way.

They are used for example for generating user defined warnings or errors as with

`#pragma warning WARNINGMSG`

or `#pragma error ERRORMSG`

or as include guard with `#pragma once` at the top of a headerfile.

What `#pragma comment` is used for, you can find nice explained here:

[What does "#pragma comment" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484434/what-does-pragma-comment-mean)

But after all, I would advise you to avoid pragmas as far it is possible, because as they are almost all, implementation defined, your code will be limited in portability if you use them.