# How to set compiling flags in cpp files (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, flags

Thank you for reading my question, I searched everywhere on the net and I couldn't find an answer.
I have a test (Olympiad in informatic) next week, The programming language that I'll be using is c++, My code gets compiled by a server which then responds whether my answer was true or false (Wrong compilation is considered as false of course), The problem is that I don't have access to the compilation phase so I can not set c++ to be compiled as c++11 (Can't set compilation flags).
My question is: Is there is any way I can add flags inside my cpp file (which will be uploaded to the server) to enable the c++11? Can it be done with predecessor with #somthing ?
Note: I have no access except to the cpp file, NO makefile, nor anything else.
Thank you For your help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: There isn't a *standard* way to do this, but it can be done with some compilers. For example, MSVC has the `#pragma comment()` directive: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3484434/4200092

Comment: @GoBusto: How's that going to help him set C++11 mode? Besides, MSVC doesn't _have_ C++03/C++11/C++14 modes; it just gives you what it gives you.

Comment: I tried the same thing trying to insert a c source file written in c++ to a c project. The compiler supports both, but the makefile was written in such a way that it only copies .c to the target.

Comment: Mind if I ask why you unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

You will have to use the C++ standard dictated by the test.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to set the compilation flags from the code but:

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Olympiad_in_Informatics)

> On each of the two competition days, the students are typically given three problems which they have to solve in five hours. Each student works on his/her own, with only a computer and no other help allowed, specifically no communication with other contestants, books etc. Usually to solve a task the contestant has to write a computer program (in C, C++ or Pascal, and occasionally FORTRAN and PHP, **C++11 is supported starting from IOI 2014**, while Java is planned to be added in IOI 2015[2])

**Emphasis mine**