# Why is the linker looking for python36_d.lib when not specified anywhere?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am compiling a Python C++ [extension module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/building.html) using VS 2017 and SWIG.

The command to the linker (for Debug configuration) for the extension module (a .pyd file) is :

```
/OUT:"D:\TFS\Dev\CGALSwig\cgal-swig-binding-4.x\build\build-python\CGAL\_CGAL_Kernel.pyd" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:/TFS/Dev/CGALSwig/cgal-swig-binding-4.x/build/build-python/CGAL/_CGAL_Kernel.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "C:\Users\helloworld\AppData\Roaming\python\libs\python36.lib" "Debug\CGAL_Kernel_cpp.lib" "D:\TFS\Dev\CGALSwig\mpfr\lib\libmpfr-4.lib" "D:\TFS\Dev\CGALSwig\gmp\lib\libgmp-10.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" /IMPLIB:"D:/TFS/Dev/CGALSwig/cgal-swig-binding-4.x/build/build-python/CGAL/Debug/CGAL_Kernel.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"D:\TFS\Dev\CGALSwig\cgal-swig-binding-4.x\build\build-python\CGAL\_CGAL_Kernel.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"_CGAL_Kernel_python.dir\Debug\_CGAL_Kernel.pyd.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"D:/TFS/Dev/CGALSwig/cgal-swig-binding-4.x/build/build-python/CGAL" /LIBPATH:"D:/TFS/Dev/CGALSwig/cgal-swig-binding-4.x/build/build-python/CGAL/Debug" /TLBID:1
```

This clearly states that the dependency is on `python36.lib` and not `python36_d.lib`.
Still, the linker throws this error :

```
LNK1104 : cannot open file 'python36_d.lib'
```

Why is the linker looking for debug LIB when it is not in the linker arguments ?

Comment: is there any autolinking in the CGAL library?

Comment: What do you mean by autolinking ?

Comment: See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484434/what-does-pragma-comment-mean). You should also make sure all the CGAL libs you build are linked to python36.lib and not the debug version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buried in the headers included by Python.h is this code:

```
#           if defined(_DEBUG)
#               pragma comment(lib,"python36_d.lib")
#           elif defined(Py_LIMITED_API)
#               pragma comment(lib,"python3.lib")
#           else
#               pragma comment(lib,"python36.lib")
#           endif /* _DEBUG */
```

The pre-processor selects `python36_d.lib` for linking automatically if `_DEBUG` is defined, i.e. a debug MSVC build.

Comment: Thanks! I had never suspected that!

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c994ffe69553cbb34f1cea6a4494d6e7657f41b0/PC/pyconfig.h#L270-L275