# What is the difference between python3.lib and python3x.lib In the Python installation libs folder?

Tags: python, windows, linker, python-bindings

I've been compiling a C library, and linking in the Python3 lib files for Python bindings. I've been using the python39.lib file as the link, but I was wondering what the difference is between the 'versioned' number (e.g. python3x.lib) vs the non versioned one (python3.lib).

In answer to a question, forgot to mention that this is compiling on windows using gcc.

Thanks

Comment: Which platform? Linux? Windows? macos? Did you check that one is not a link to the other?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Platform is windows. No i havent, how would I determine that one is linked to another?

Comment: I think @yoonghm's answer contains what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python3.lib` only contains key library functions used by cpython program (or C extension for Python). `python3x.lib` (such as `python38.lib`, `python39.lib`) contains the full library functions. You should link to `python3.lib` so that your build configuration is not affected by minor Python version upgrade such as from 3.8 to 3.9.

The linking is very platform and compiler dependent. See code comment in the `PC/pyconfig.h` (See reference [3]).

Additional info

1. [PEP384 - Linkage](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0384/#id22)
2. [Stackoverflow question on how MSVC linker looks for specific Python debug library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522969/why-is-the-linker-looking-for-python36-d-lib-when-not-specified-anywhere)
3. [PC/pyconfig.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9cc9e277254023c0ca08e1a9e379fd89475ca9c2/PC/pyconfig.h#L270)

Comment: No answer on the `python3x.lib` which is the issue?

Comment: The question is about the `lib` file, so your answer should mention the file, not point to a link where the author can maybe find the file.

Comment: @yoonghm That is interesting, thanks. Any chance you have a link to a source i can read into about this?