# Why MSVC linker looks for a specific library when not asked to?

Tags: python, c++, linker

I have a python project containing python bindings to a C++ library mylib.lib. Mylib.lib is dependent on different libs such as `boost`, `ICU`, `xml++` etc. In my `setup.py` pipeline I have a part where I have to compile python bindings (`pybind11`).

Because this entire setup is new to me, I work on it incrementally. I added all required headers and the compilation itself went smoothly  - linker outputed a lot unresolved external symbols which was ok at this stage and so I decided to link `mylib.lib` and then `LINK.EXE` asked about very specific library:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib'
```

I have no problem linking boost in `setup.py`, I just don't understand how linker can be so specific. I did not ask about that library and in case I have missed something, I made linker to be verbose and there is no boost mention in the command. Any clues?

Cheers!

---

**Edit**: This happens only with Boost, rest of libraries are ignored and I have to manually link them.

Comment: One of the libraries you are using is probably using that library.  What boost libraries are you using?

Comment: You say the response yourself: "Mylib.lib is dependent on different libs such as boost"

Comment: Look for msvc specific #pragma comment(lib  in the code of mylib [What does "#pragma comment" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484434/what-does-pragma-comment-mean)

Comment: @AnonMail program_options filesystem system regex @Manuel, right but it's also dependent on `ICU` and other libraries, so what's special about `boost`?

Comment: @S.M. I couldn't find anything

Comment: It is in the headers for boost.