# How to link third party library into my project in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dllexport

I am trying to import C++ third party library:

```
1- FKAttend.h
2- FKAttend.lib
3- FKAttend.dll
```

In header file it uses implicit linking to call the functions

```
 #ifdef _FKATTEND
    #define FP_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport) APIENTRY
#else
    #define FP_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

My step in Visual Studio 2019
1- I have included path of header file
2- Linked FKAttend.lib by adding FKAttend.lib to "Additional Dependencies" and FKAttend.lib file path into "Additional Library Directories"
And I get this error when I call a simple function from `FKAttend.h`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vouYr.jpg)

I tried same thing in Eclipse, also I got an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAM7M.jpg)

Comment: Please, post the error logs as text (code), not images.

Comment: There is no 'implicit linking'. There are [_pragmas_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484434/what-does-pragma-comment-mean) in headers to tell linker what to do. The question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add additional libraries to Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project)

Comment: Can you show the contents of FKAttend.h?

Comment: The compiler assumes this library was written in C++, note the mangled function name in the linker error message.  Surely it was not, wrap the #include with `extern "C" { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

According to your description of the problem, please check the following two points:

1. Please check the path of the .lib file, it is best to use an absolute path to reduce the probability of error.
2. I suggest you should check if the platform and configuration settings are consistent with the build time.

[image]

[image]

I suggest you could set Configuration and Platform in the property settings to ALL.

[image]