# How to add third-party libraries without repeating each project in vs2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I build many projects in a solution. One of them use third-party.If another project use this project, it need set the same third-party too. It's too trouble. I want to know it is there any method to solve this problem?

Comment: You can add a `#pragma comment(lib, "thirdp.lib")` line to one of the source or header files of your project (the one that needs the 3rd-party library). The linked duplicate explains more. (Sorry, I've assumed you are using C or C++ ... ping me if that's *not* the case.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "#pragma comment" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484434/what-does-pragma-comment-mean)